Can the Deep's Octopus girlfriend breathe while being out of water or not?
In The Boys, season 4, ep 7, The Deep is seen flirting with his lover, an Octopus, in bed; they have a conversation and have a good laugh.
Later in the same episode, when the Deep is confronted by this Octopus for cheating on her with Sage, the Deep breaks the Octopus's water tank and the Octopus starts yelling in pain, complaining about it could not breathe and presumely dies behind a shut door while claiming it loves the Deep.
We have two conflicting scenes in this episode, can this Octopus survive whie being out of water?

According to How long can an octopus survive out of the water? on our sister site Biology Stack Exchange, octopuses can survive out of water for a short amount of time.
The octopus' respiratory system depends on oxygen-rich water being pumped through the gills.
However, octopuses can also absorb a small amount of oxygen from water through their skin. Octopuses are known to leave the water for short amounts of time.
How long they can survive depends on the size of the skin surface area compared to the metabolic rate (the size of the skin area goes up with the square of the length, whereas the metabolic rate is related to muscle mass and thus goes up with the cube of the length – hence, smaller octopuses will have a higher ratio of skin surface area to muscle mass than larger ones, thus, smaller octopuses will be able to survive longer), moisture of the skin, and the amount of oxygen in the moisture.
From the point of the episode, we can speculate that, when The Deep is making love to Ambrosia, he is keeping her moist with well-oxygenated water … or, it's just a plot error by the writers.

It wasn't a plot error, it was a deliberate setup and gag payoff. They established in the first scene that she can live out of water but not indefinitely then later she "dies" rather quickly in a sad scene.. only for her to suddenly and comidically start up again after you think it is done because as they established earlier, she can survive a while out of water.
